# vsftpd LAN and WAN access configuration

Tags: 20.04, ftp, ip, vsftpd

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS baremetal, with the latest version of `vsftpd`. I have a very small FTP server at home, but I'm facing the following issue:

If I set the local IP on `pasv_address` (`pasv_address=192.168.0.15`), I can connect locally, but not externally. If I set my external IP on `pasv_address`, I can't connect locally.

Is there any way to be able to use the FTP server, both LAN and WAN?

Comment: I thought you just DON'T specify pasv_address as the default is `none - the address is taken from the incoming connected socket`

Comment: do you think it's safe like that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, using my WAN IP on my internal FTP client. Probably not the best solution, but did the job.